# Material Web Components form not sending input fields

Tags: javascript, material-ui, material-design, material-components-web

I'm trying to implement a theme called Material Admin Pro.
They have login page [see here](https://material-admin-pro.startbootstrap.com/app-auth-login-basic.html)

I changed the Login button to mwc-button which on click will submit the form.

The strange thing is, the input fields created with mwc-textfield aren't posted, only the fields that I've added manually (like the fields `testname` and `token`)

You can find my JSfiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj3nrq5x/)
Which sends the form to [this post bin container](https://ptsv2.com/t/zbufy-1619279817)

When I inspect the HTML, I do see input fields being created [(see screenshot)](https://pasteboard.co/JYPGF0P.png)
I did notice the `flex` behind the elements, so maybe that's the problem?

It's my first time with material web components, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong